# Polynomial returned by `lagrange` doesn't evaluate to the interpolated points

Tags: python, scipy, polynomial-math

On the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
def fib(n):
     a, b = 0, 1
     for _ in range(n):
         a, b = b, a+b
     return a
x = np.array(range(64))
y = np.array([fib(n) for n in xrange(64)])
P = lagrange(x, y)
print P(10)
```

I use scipy to create a polynomial `P` from interpolating a function (`fib`) on 64 points. As such, I expect that, `P(n) == fib(n)` for any `0 <= n < 64`. Instead, for `P(10)`, for example, I get `-248014823183360.0` instead of `55` (`fib(10)`). I suppose this is a precision error somewhere, but I'm not sure where. How can I construct a polynomial function `P` which satisfies this expectation?

Comment: From [the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html):Warning: This implementation is numerically unstable. Do not expect to be able to use more than about 20 points even if they are chosen optimally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the numpy.polyfit which is more stable on higher polynomial rank

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange

N = 30

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = b, a+b
    return a


x = np.arange(N)
y = np.array([fib(i) for i in x])


P = np.polyfit(x, y, N)

n = int(N/2)
print ((y[n], np.polyval(P, n))) 

L = lagrange(x, y)
print ((y[n], L(n)))
```

610, 609.9896

610, -645662.4698

Over that, I would say that polynomial fit is rarely a good solution on big number of points. If you are interested on Fibonacci series (or is it just an example ?), you can use the analytical formula based on powers of the golden number that you can derive to floating indices (Have a look to the Fibonacci Wikipedia page).